# Linux 'df' command not showing root filesystem?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rackspace, rackspace-cloud, df

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 at Rackspace. What could cause the root fs to not appear here?

```
# df

Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
none                   4     0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             2021824    12   2021812   1% /dev
tmpfs             409756   252    409504   1% /run
none                5120     0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             2048772     0   2048772   0% /run/shm
none              102400     0    102400   0% /run/user
```

Comment: What about `df -a`?

Comment: does the uuid for your root fs match the one for it in /etc/fstab ?

Comment: Run the `mount` command and see if it shows up there.

Comment: `df` uses the `/etc/mtab` file, for some reason your root filesystem isn't listed. You could check `/proc/mounts` for the appropriate line and paste that into `/etc/mtab`.

Comment: Can you specify contents of `/etc/fstab`, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my experience this issue is because some NFS mount point is not mounted properly.
for easy troubleshooting try to unmount any NFS mount point and use the command. If issue is not resolved then just create the backup copy of the fstab file create new fstab file don't add NFS mount point and try to remount your all mount points. if you get the output in df -h then its your time to troubleshoot your NFS mount point.